# Convert MNIST database to .csv : ord() error occurred

Tags: python, mnist, ord

I would like to convert the original MNIST database to csv file.
I used the code from https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/

But I got some error about ord()
I know ord() should take one string as the element, but I don't know why this happened without understanding the structure of the original database.

```
def convert(imgf, labelf, outf, n):
    f = open(imgf, "rb")
    o = open(outf, "w")
    l = open(labelf, "rb")

    f.read(16)
    l.read(8)
    images = []

    for i in range(n):
        image = [ord(l.read(1))]
        for j in range(28*28):
            image.append(ord(f.read(1)))
        images.append(image)

    for image in images:
        o.write(",".join(str(pix) for pix in image)+"\n")
    f.close()
    o.close()
    l.close()

convert("train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz","mnist_train.csv", 60000)
convert("t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz","mnist_test.csv", 10000)
```

This is the error message that I've got

`ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found`

Comment: Probably because  `l.read(1)` returned an empty string, meaning that you have reached the end of the file.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I don't think so, because we used range(n) which does not include the end of the file

Comment: maybe try to replace `28*28` by `28*28-1` as you already `read(1)`

Comment: @BenoitdeMenthière It did not work, showing same error.

Comment: To debug try to check the length of your file and count how many time you call read

Answer (score 0):

If the sizes of files is same as on the website

- training set images (9912422 bytes),
- training set labels (28881 bytes),
- test set images (1648877 bytes)
- test set labels (4542 bytes)

**then you are trying to convert compressed file**. You need to first extract all the files.

You can use 7z for it.

```
7z x train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
7z x train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
7z x t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
7z x t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
```

Then in python file you just need to change names of files to match newly extracted files.